# What is the content delivery network of Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia

I am interested in how Wikipedia handles its large load so quickly across the globe. Is Wikipedia using a commercial CDN solution, or something else?

I did search about this topic, but because of the nature of what search engine users are commonly interested in, search results only return documentation about CDNs.

A [CDN finder](http://www.cdnplanet.com/tools/cdnfinder/#site:http://en.wikipedia.org/) also did not return any results.

I had a quick look at [The Wikimedia Meta Wiki: Wikimedia Servers](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia_servers), but it is stated that the article is quite outdated, but gives the hint that Wikimedia is not using any corporate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the HTTP response headers for Wikipedia you can see they are distributing the load across two different subdomains: eqiad.wmnet and esams.wmnet.com. They have a little bit of info about it on the [Wikipedia CDN](https://torrus.wikimedia.org/torrus/CDN?path=/Varnish/) page.

Most likely this is an in-house CDN, built by them.

If you are looking for a CDN I recommend checking out [CDN Comparison](http://cdncomparison.com/).

Side note: As of May 4th, 2016 they also are using HTTP/2.